# AVPlayerItem status AVPlayerStatusFailed when playing video

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayer, avplayeritem

I implemented Video Playback for multiple videos with `AVPlayer`. When I play next video, sometimes it shows this error messages:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped"
>   UserInfo=0x1744796c0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x170055db0 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12939.)",
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server is not correctly configured.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}

I found that **11850 error** is: `AVErrorServerIncorrectlyConfigured` which means that

> The HTTP server sending the media
>   resource is not configured as expected. This might mean that the
>   server does not support byte range requests.

Please help me with this case, this is my code to play video

```
- (void)playVideoWithUrl:(NSString *) videoUrl 
{
   if (player != nil) {
   [player.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
   [player.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"];
   }
AVURLAsset * asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl]
                                            options:nil];    
AVPlayerItem * item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
// Add KVO to detech status of loading video
[item addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"status"
          options:0
          context:nil];
// Add KVO to detech when playback is loading buffer successfully
[item addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"
          options:0
          context:nil];
// Detect when playback completed
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[player currentItem]];
[player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
[player play];
}
```

Comment: Is it solved or not?

Comment: No, I haven't found the root cause yet. But I found another solution for my own project, I downloaded and played videos from Document directory instead of playing them directly from server.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Have you found a workaround for server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823411/avplayer-fails-to-play-video-sometimes